# How do I refresh a div element after AJAX succes?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Posting this because I found a lot of jquery answers, but no raw javascript answers.

So I have a function to post a comment to a comment section, and I want the comment section to refresh after posting a comment, But for some reason my code isn't working.

The code for loading the comment section:

```
function loadCommentSection() {
 console.log("loading section")
  imgid = imgid.replace("img/pic (", "");
  imgid = imgid.replace(").jpg", "");
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("commentsection").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "commentsection.php?imgid=" + imgid, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

and the code for submitting the comment:

```
function submitComment() {
  var title = document.getElementById("title").value;
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var comment = document.getElementById("comment").value;

  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "comment.php?imgid=" + imgid + "&title=" + title + "&comment=" + comment + "&name=" + name, true);

  xhttp.send();
  loadCommentSection();


}
```

The problem is that the loadCommentSection function in the submitComment function isn't executing.

Comment: Sending isn't done synchronously, thus you have to load the comments in your event which signals the request is complete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should allow the comment to be sent to the server and be registered before calling `loadCommentSection`. So, it is probably best to call it when the response becomes available:

```
function submitComment() {
  var title = document.getElementById("title").value;
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var comment = document.getElementById("comment").value;

  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      loadCommentSection(); // <<---- moved here.
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "comment.php?imgid=" + imgid + "&title=" + title + "&comment=" + comment + "&name=" + name, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```